# Привет всем, возникла идея написать телеграм бота, который будет писать каждое утро "привет". Помогите додумать алгоритм

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;

namespace svetlana_ragulina_bot
{
    class Program
    {
        static TelegramBotClient Bot;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bot = new TelegramBotClient("793657943:AAHC8lp9v_cdZL3Z3osPG8uYjjET_4TuJ_U");
            Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage; // функция OnMessage - Позволяет отправлять сообщение
            Bot.OnCallbackQuery += Bot_OnCallbackQuery;

            var Me = Bot.GetMeAsync().Result;

            Console.WriteLine(Me.FirstName);
            Bot.StartReceiving(); //Принимает сообщение 
            Console.ReadLine();
            Bot.StopReceiving(); //Останавливает поток сообщений
        }

        private static void Bot_OnCallbackQuery(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = e.Message;
            if(message == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var name = $"{message.From.FirstName}{message.From.LastName}";
                Console.WriteLine($"{name} отправил сообщение: '{ message.Text}'");

                switch (message.Text)
                {
                    case "/start":
                        string start = "Привет, я бот " +
                            "Список команд: \n" +
                            "/activate";
                       await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, start);
                        break;
                    case "/activate":
                        string activate = "Отлично, теперь я каждое утро буду писать 'Hello'";
                        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, activate);
                        DateTime s = new DateTime();
                        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(8, 30, 0);
                        s = s.Date + ts;
                        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, s.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: для таких дел нужен таймер

Comment: @tym32167, кинешь пару ссылок годных?

Comment: да не вопрос, [Timers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers)

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо